# C++ Inheritance and passing vector references

Tags: c++, inheritance, vector, reference

Given the following code compiles and runs with no error

```c
class A {
public:
  std::vector<int> i;
  void add(std::vector<int> &v) { i = v; }
};

class B {
public:
  B(A &a, std::vector<int> &v) { a.add(v); }
};
```

```c
int main() {
  A a;
  std::vector<int> v{1, 2, 3, 4};
  B b(a, v);
  return 0;
}
```

If I add a class `C`

```c
class C : B {
public:
  std::vector<int> v{1, 2, 3, 4};
  C(A &a) : B(a, v) {}
};
```

and change main

```c
int main() {
  A a;
  C c(a);
  return 0;
}
```

I get

```bash
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::bad_array_new_length'
  what():  std::bad_array_new_length
zsh: IOT instruction (core dumped)
```

I don't even know how to title this because I don't understand why this would possibly fail

I was expecting the second version of main to do the same as the first version of main but it gives a strange error that makes no sense to me

Comment: `B` is constructed before the members of `C` are constructed. This includes `v`.

Comment: `C::v` is used before its constructed, in `B(a, v)`, that's UB so you get strange errors.

Comment: @CaptainObvlious I would like to have many classes inherit B, and have them all automatically call add when constructed and pass a vector class member. How would I do it automatically without using B's constructor, since C is constructed after?

Comment: Does `A::add` need to take a non-const reference, so that it cannot accept a temporary? And same for `B` constructor?

Comment: Does every class derived from `B` need to have its own separate `vector` member? Can't `B` carry this member instead, so that all derived classes inherit it? What are you really trying to achieve with this design?

Comment: @IgorTandetnik nope, better to be const, thanks!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One possible solution:

```
class C : B {
public:
  std::vector<int> v;
  C(A &a) : C(a, {1, 2, 3, 4}) {}
private:
  C(A& a, const std::vector<int>& vv)
    : B(a, vv), v(vv) {}
};
```

This attempts to preserve the semantics of the original code to the extent possible (even while they don't necessarily make sense to me).

Comment: In case you're wondering what I'm doing, I have a Can bus class, CanDevice class, and Devices that inherit the CanDevice. I add a vector of IDs and callbacks to a hash map of the can bus because the can bus is listening for messages and executing corresponding callbacks. I just didn't include that code because this was the root of my problem